# install 32bit eclipse parallel to 64bit eclipse in 64bit ubuntu

Tags: java, 64-bit, eclipse, 32-bit, jdk

My preferred java IDE is [eclipse](https://eclipse.org).

Since I own a lego robot (NXJ) I want to use [Java For Lego Mindstorms](http://www.lejos.org/). I found out I have to use all 32bit architecture since the usb drives won't work otherwise. ("all 32bit architecture" includes eclipse and the jdk)

How to install a second eclipse?

My first try was just to redownload the eclipse installer, for 32bit architecture this time. When I start the installer from command line, I get the following error:

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: You have loaded library /home/me/Downloads/eclipse-installer/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_1.1.551.v20171108-1834/eclipse_1630.so which might have disabled stack guard. The VM will try to fix the stack guard now.
It's highly recommended that you fix the library with 'execstack -c <libfile>', or link it with '-z noexecstack'.

Eclipse Installer:
JVM terminated. Exit code=13
/usr/bin/java
-Xms256M
-Xmx1024M
-jar /home/me/Downloads/eclipse-installer//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.4.0.v20161219-1356.jar
-os linux
-ws gtk
-arch x86
-showsplash
-launcher /home/me/Downloads/eclipse-installer/eclipse-inst
-name Eclipse Installer
--launcher.library /home/me/Downloads/eclipse-installer//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_1.1.551.v20171108-1834/eclipse_1630.so
-startup /home/me/Downloads/eclipse-installer//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.4.0.v20161219-1356.jar
--launcher.appendVmargs
-exitdata 18e0024
-data @noDefault
-vm /usr/bin/java
-vmargs
-Xms256M
-Xmx1024M
-jar /home/me/Downloads/eclipse-installer//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.4.0.v20161219-1356.jar
```

So, how to install a 32bit eclipse to make LeJOS run?